# How to not refresh page's previous field input values after press submit

Tags: php, html

I have an input like this:

```
<input value="<?php echo $formdata['title'] ?>" type="text" name="title" id="Editbox2">
```

This is an edit page, I load database data into fields with echo, replace them, and hit submit to update them.

But when I hit submit it refreshes the old data onto browser's fields, how can I prevent this?

Comment: Please show the complete logic. After submit you have the parse the data and may replace/insert into your database.

Maybe you shoud put a helper variable inside like saved=1 which is only there when the form was submitted as least once. If saved is not 1, you know to pull it from database.

Comment: @Markus Zeller Well, my only issue is this client-side field thing, nothing to do with how I update/delete the row on the database, I've already managed to fix it w/ a simple HTML trick shown in the comments of 1 of the answers

Answer (score 0):

Submit your form using ajax request with jquery submit.

Use action="javascript:;" for the form tag

Comment: Thanks for your help skillful kitchen coder, using AJAX it's a bit of an overkill for what I'm doing, still a newb, I'll explore it better eventually, but I've managed to fix it with a simple HTML trick that I've referenced on the other answer's comments

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the script with javascript, then prevent the default behaviour, which is refreshing the page. Here is an example:

*I haven't tested this, but from what I recall this is what I used to do. Let me know if it doesn't work, I'll give other suggestions.

```
<form>
  <!-- elements inside -->
  <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and in your javascript have the following:

```
<script>
  $("#submit-btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // handle form here with your JS
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I wasn't able to get your jQuery code working anyways, but I've managed to fix it with a known HTML trick


By adding `target="myiframe"` inside `<form>` tag and and empty iframe
`<iframe style="display:none;" src="" name="myiframe"></iframe>`